# How to set monofont to Source Code Pro Light

Tags: listings, font-encodings, beramono

I would like to know how to go about setting the monofont to Source Code Pro Light.

With the code given below, the `ttfamily` gives this result:

[image]

This is the code that I currently have:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
    BoldFont=Source Code Pro,%
    Scale=MatchLowercase
]

\newcommand{\codetextcol}[2]{{\footnotesize{\ttfamily{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}}}
\newcommand{\codetext}[1]{{\footnotesize{\ttfamily{#1}}}}

\usepackage{fourier}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
 % detect if next step is an obstacle
                if bug.isoccupied(robot + [dx; dy])
                    bug.message('(%d,%d) obstacle!', n);
                    bug.H(bug.j,:) = robot; % define hit point
                    bug.step = 2;
                    % get a list of all the points around the obstacle
                    bug.edge = edgelist(bug.occgridnav == 0, robot);
                    %bug.k = 2;  % skip the first edge point, we are already there
                    bug.k = size(bug.edge,2)
                else
                    n = robot + [dx; dy];
                end
            end % step 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

The Header of the ARFF file contains the name of the relation (\codetextcol{blue}{@RELATION})\index{arff syntax!"@relation}, (\codetextcol{blue}{@relation}) a list of the attributes (\codetextcol{blue}{@ATTRIBUTE})\index{arff syntax!"@attribute} (the columns in the data), and their types.  Note that \codetextcol{blue}{@RELATION}, \codetextcol{blue}{@ATTRIBUTE} and \codetextcol{blue}{@DATA}\index{arff syntax!"@data} are case insensitive.

\lstinputlisting[%firstline = 236,
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
caption={[First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm]{First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm}},
label = mat:line246]{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asssuming you employ LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX -- why else use the `\setmonofont` instruction? -- to compile your document, I suggest you

- get rid of the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}` (since the latter command changes the "teletype" or monospaced font to Computer Modern Teletype) and
- add the instruction `\usepackage{fontspec}` immediately before `\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[...]`.

Separately, it's been several years since it was necessary to load the `filecontents` package in order to employ `filecontents` environments.

Incidentally, `\ttfamily` doesn't take an argument that's delimited by curly braces.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
%%%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro} % <-- probably not needed
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} % <-- new
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
    BoldFont=Source Code Pro,%
    Scale=MatchLowercase
    ]

\newcommand{\codetextcol}[2]{%
  {\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\codetext}[1]{{\footnotesize\ttfamily #1}}

\usepackage{fourier}

%%%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
 % detect if next step is an obstacle
      if bug.isoccupied(robot + [dx; dy])
          bug.message('(%d,%d) obstacle!', n);
          bug.H(bug.j,:) = robot; % define hit point
          bug.step = 2;
          % get a list of all the points around the obstacle
          bug.edge = edgelist(bug.occgridnav == 0, robot);
          %bug.k = 2;  % skip the first edge point, we are already there
          bug.k = size(bug.edge,2)
      else
          n = robot + [dx; dy];
      end
   end % step 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\noindent
The Header of the ARFF file contains the name of the relation (\codetextcol{blue}{@RELATION})\index{arff syntax!"@relation}, (\codetextcol{blue}{@relation}) a list of the attributes (\codetextcol{blue}{@ATTRIBUTE})\index{arff syntax!"@attribute} (the columns in the data), and their types.  Note that \codetextcol{blue}{@RELATION}, \codetextcol{blue}{@ATTRIBUTE} and \codetextcol{blue}{@DATA}\index{arff syntax!"@data} are case insensitive.

\lstinputlisting[%firstline = 236,
  backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  caption={[First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm]{%
    First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm}},
  label = mat:line246]{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious to know whether `scale=MatchLowercase` is must or optional? Please advise.

Comment: @MadyYuvi - For the present version of the OP’s code, I’d say “neither”. The issue is that the instruction `\usepackage{fourier}` (which sets the main text font) currently comes *after* the `\setmonofont` instruction, making  the associated `Scale` option more or less meaningless. I can only assume that the OP will eventually get around to sorting out these matters.